# How can i get hash code from url when i write url and press enter?

Tags: jquery, url, hashtag

I have this url: example.com/index.html#tab-1

I write into browser following url **example.com/index.html#tab-1** and press enter - page will not load.

I want to get the parameter tab1 and load content with id tab1.

My code:

I call this functions:

```
//to load

showTabContent(gethash);


showTabContent: function(id)
        {
            if(id != null)
            {
                var tabid = id.split("-");
                $("#tab"+tabid[1]).show();
            }
        },

gethash: function()
        {
            var hash = window.location.hash;
            if($.trim(hash) != "") return hash;
            else return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to parse the URL into an object: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/parsing-urls-with-the-dom/. After you get the object back, you can use the properties of the object to get the parts of the URL you want.

A similar answer was provided in this post: [String URL to json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469443/string-url-to-json-object)

Answer (score 0):

Check this jQuery plugin:

- http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/
- http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/docs/files/jquery-ba-hashchange-js.html

JS File: https://raw.github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange/master/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js

The solution for your code:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#tab-1">Tab1</a>
<div id="tab1"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
obj = {
    checkHash: function(){
        $(window).hashchange( function(){
            var hash = location.hash;
            obj.showTabContent(hash);
        })
    },
    showTabContent: function(id)
    {
        var tabid = id.split("-");
        $("#tab"+tabid[1]).show();
    } 
};

//init
obj.checkHash();
```