# How to get contents of URL into a string variable using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm trying to get the JSON from this URL into variable

This bit of code successfully puts it in a div element

```
$("#siteloader").html('<object data="MYURL">');
```

But I want the contents of that div inside a string variable rather than in the div.

I've also tried the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    url : "MYURL", // ?callback=?
    success: function(data){
        // do stuff with data
    }
});
```

But this shows a syntax error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : " "getfixes:1" in the javascript console when I try it in chrome.

Is it possible for me to just get the contents of a URL as a string in the data variable?

Comment: it seems the json returned from url is illegal. open the url in browser and try to assign the result to a var in the console. like the following:

var obj = //paste the result from url

you'll get an error.

Comment: It seems like it! 

Can I retrieve it as a string? Surely if I retrieve the JSON as a string it shouldn't have parsing errors right?

I don't know how to retrieve it as a string though :/

Answer (score 0):

there is a external library according to this post: [String URL to json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469443/string-url-to-json-object)

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/parsing-urls-with-the-dom/