# what is /#/ in URL?

Tags: url, vue-router

I use `vue-cli` created an empty Hello World project,
add a `HelloWorld2.vue` in `components` which basically copy from `HelloWorld.vue`.
then add the new one to the `router/index.js` like this:

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: HelloWorld
    },
    {
      path: '/HelloWorld2',
      component: HelloWorld2
    }
  ]
})
```

Question:
When I trying to access `HelloWorld2`

```
1. localhost/#/HelloWorld2 //right
2. localhost/HelloWorld2   //wrong, redirect to HelloWorld
```

What's meaning of `/#/`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of Hash(#) in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850093/usage-of-hash-in-url)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the hash symbol, you should pass `mode: 'history',` to your router as:

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [...],
  mode: 'history'
})
```

This will remove the hash `#` from your URLs