# How to assign unique url params to faq

Tags: javascript

I have a couple of divs of questions for an faq. The faq was coded in a way that the active panel for a question expands when clicked but the first question opens by default. Now I want to make each panel to have its unique URL when clicked.

```
<div class="row faq_links">
   <h1 class="faq-header">Frequently Asked Questions</h1>

<div id="accordion" class="faq-column">

      <div id="faq1" class="panel tabcontent">
        <p class="header">What is ....?</p>
        <p class="body">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      </div>

      <div id="faq2" class="panel tabcontent" onClick="goTo(this)">
        <p class="header">How does ... Work?</p>
        <p class="body">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      </div>

      <div id="faq3" class="panel tabcontent">
        <p class="header">Who are ...?</p>
        <p class="body">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      </div>

   </div>
```

```
function goTo (panel) {
  var url, faqs, para
    url = window.loaction;
    faqs = faq.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");

  for (i = 0; i < faqs.length; i++) {
    para = faqs[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];

  if (url == panel) {
    url.replace(url + id);

  }
}
```

I want to make each panel to have its unique URL when clicked but I'm stuck.

Comment: What is `faq.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent")`? Based on the code you've provided(which has some other issues) that would return `undefined`.

Comment: You mean an unique [hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21850206/5568741)?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a typo in your code

```
url = window.loaction;
```

change to `window.location`

Also, window.location is an object and will never be equal to `panel`, so the condition would be always false. and `id` is undefined and will throw an error,

You are probably looking for something like

```
hash = window.location.hash;
if(hash!=panel) //assuming panel is the hash(that is, id of the clicked div)
  window.location.hash = panel;
```

Comment: Thank You Dhananjai, your answer was helpful

Comment: feel free to accept the answer if it helped, would be useful for future users as reference