# Steam market parsing

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, steam

I have a [link](https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_ProPlayer%5B%5D=any&category_730_StickerCapsule%5B%5D=any&category_730_TournamentTeam%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&category_730_Type%5B%5D=tag_CSGO_Type_Knife&appid=730#p1_price_asc)

And it have "_price_asc" in the end, it makes ascending sorting. when I follow this link in the browser sorting works fine.

[image: screenshot1]

But! If I try to parse items links using bs4, this gives me items with random prices, i.e. ascending sorting does not work

[image: screenshot2]

what am I doing wrong?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_ProPlayer%5B%5D=any&category_730_StickerCapsule%5B%5D=any&category_730_TournamentTeam%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&category_730_Type%5B%5D=tag_CSGO_Type_Knife&appid=730#p1_price_asc'

total_links = ''

page = urlopen(link)
bs_page = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), features="html.parser")
objects = bs_page.findAll(class_="market_listing_row_link")

for g in range(10):
    total_links += str(objects[g]["href"]) + '\n'
print(total_links)
```

Comment: this page uses JavaScript to sort data in table but `BeautifulSoup`/`urllib` can't run `JavaScript`. You may need `Selenium` to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. OR get all data and prices and use Python `sort()` or `sorted()` to sort it.

Comment: I thought about sorting, it will take a lot of time, but okay
thank you for answer

Comment: sorting doesn't take so long time - if you keed data as `(price, link)` then `sort()` will sort it by `price` because it is first.

Comment: I found url which gives sorted data - so it doesn't need Selenium and it doesn't need to read all pages and sort in Python. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page uses JavaScript to get sorted data but `BeautifulSoup`/`urllib` can't run JavaScript

But using `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab: `Network`, filter: `XHR`) I found out that `JavaScript` reads JSON data from some url and there is HTML with sorted data - so you can use this url with `BeautifulSoup` to get sorted data.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

# new url 

link = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&start=0&count=10&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=price&sort_dir=asc&appid=730&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_ProPlayer%5B%5D=any&category_730_StickerCapsule%5B%5D=any&category_730_TournamentTeam%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&category_730_Type%5B%5D=tag_CSGO_Type_Knife'

page = urlopen(link)

data = json.loads(page.read().decode())
html = data['results_html']

bs_page = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
objects = bs_page.findAll(class_="market_listing_row_link")

data = []

for g in objects:
    link  = g["href"]
    price = g.find('span', {'data-price': True}).text
    data.append((price, link))

print("\n".join(f"{price} | {link}" for price, link in data))
```

Result:

```
$67.43 USD | https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Navaja%20Knife%20%7C%20Urban%20Masked%20%28Field-Tested%29
$67.70 USD | https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Navaja%20Knife%20%7C%20Night%20Stripe%20%28Field-Tested%29
$69.00 USD | https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Navaja%20Knife%20%7C%20Night%20Stripe%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29
$69.52 USD | https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Navaja%20Knife%20%7C%20Scorched%20%28Battle-Scarred%29
$69.48 USD | https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Navaja%20Knife%20%7C%20Safari%20Mesh%20%28Field-Tested%29
$70.32 USD | https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Navaja%20Knife%20%7C%20Forest%20DDPAT%20%28Battle-Scarred%29
$70.90 USD | https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Navaja%20Knife%20%7C%20Night%20Stripe%20%28Well-Worn%29
$70.52 USD | https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Navaja%20Knife%20%7C%20Forest%20DDPAT%20%28Field-Tested%29
$71.99 USD | https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Navaja%20Knife%20%7C%20Boreal%20Forest%20%28Field-Tested%29
$72.08 USD | https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Navaja%20Knife%20%7C%20Scorched%20%28Field-Tested%29
```

---

**BTW:** Here is my first version which was reading from old url and sorting in Python. But it can sort only data on first page. To get better result it would have to read all pages - and it would take a lot of time.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_ProPlayer%5B%5D=any&category_730_StickerCapsule%5B%5D=any&category_730_TournamentTeam%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&category_730_Type%5B%5D=tag_CSGO_Type_Knife&appid=730#p1_price_asc'
page = urlopen(link)

bs_page = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), features="html.parser")
objects = bs_page.findAll(class_="market_listing_row_link")

data = []

for g in objects:
    link  = g["href"]
    price = g.find('span', {'data-price': True})['data-price']
    price = int(price)
    data.append((price,link))

data = sorted(data)

print("\n".join(f"${price/100} USD | {link}" for price, link in data))
```

Comment: wow, you literally did all the work for me, thanks again for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this is happening is because if you look at the following link

```
https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_ProPlayer%5B%5D=any&category_730_StickerCapsule%5B%5D=any&category_730_TournamentTeam%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&category_730_Type%5B%5D=tag_CSGO_Type_Knife&appid=730#p1_price_asc
```

The link ends with "***#p1_price_asc***" , the hashtag is an indicator of a page marker of sorts, here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850093/usage-of-hash-in-url) that gives a through explanation. Basically "#" in the url is usually called by javascript functions.

Since you are downloading the page using:

```
page = urlopen(link)
```

This does not result in the javascript function calls that does the sorting. I highly recommend the link on hashtag as that is doing a much better job of explaining than I am.

---

Now In regards to how to achieve what you want, you have two options:

1. Use selenium library as this emulates a browser
2. Keep using what you are using, and manually sort the data yourself(its trivial and you will learn more)

I would personally recommend method 2, as learning selenium can be a bit of a pain in the ass, and not usually worth it... in my opinion.