# How Could I make This Redirect To Another (External) Website

Tags: php, wordpress, web, wordpress-theming

How Could I make This Redirect To Another (External) Website, unsure

```html
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#news">Link Accounts</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Simply add social media links, or any website url inside href attribute, ex: `href="https://www.youtube.com/ncxsio"`. Check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) for more details about html links. Please do some research before asking.

Comment: Please be precise in formatting the post content, some of the code was not visible to other users.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of Hash(#) in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850093/usage-of-hash-in-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a class="nav-link" href="EXTERNAL_WEBSITE_LINK_HERE">Link Accounts</a>
```

Eg:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="https://www.google.com">Link Accounts</a>
```