# I can't access search parameter values that start with '#'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to access my search parameters. I can access the value of my `name` key but I can't seem to access the value of my `value` key. I think it has something to do with the hash `#` at the begining.

Here is my URL

- http://localhost:3000/all/?name=Color&value=#03FFF7

```
const queryString = window.location.search
      if (queryString) {
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString)
        const name = urlParams.get('name')
        const value = urlParams.get('value')
        console.log(`This is the ${value}`)
        this.setState({ name, nameValue: value })
      }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850093/usage-of-hash-in-url

Comment: because # meaning different in url `console.log(new URL("http://localhost:3000/all/?name=Color&value=#03FFF7").hash);`

Comment: only one way: remove `#`