# What is the behavior of Hash(#) in query string

Tags: java, url, web-applications, url-encoding

I am sending the below url with query string. In the query string one parameter 
        "approverCmt" has value with hash(#).

```
    "/abc/efd/xyz.jas?approverCmt=Transaction Log #459505&batchNm=XS_10APR2015_082224&mfrNm=Timberland"
```

In server side when I tried to retrieve it from the request I get

```
    approverCmt = Transaction Log  -----> "#459505" is missing
    batchNm = null
    mfrNm = null
```

And If I remove hash(#) from query string or If I replace # with %23 every thing works fine

I don't understand why I am getting null for one parameter if another parameter contains a hash(#) symbol.

Appreciate if any one can explain.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280212/getting-the-full-url-including-the-query-string-after-hash)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is known as the "fragment identifier".

As mentioned in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier):

> The `fragment identifier` introduced by a hash mark # is the optional last part of a `URL` for a document. It is typically used to identify a portion of that document.

The part after the `#` is info for the `client`. It is not sent to the server. Put everything only the browser needs here.

You can use the `encodeURIComponent()` function in JavaScript to encode special characters in a URL, so that `#` characters are converted to other characters that way you can be sure your whole URL will be sent to the server.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning everything put after this character (if non-encoded) is not sent to the server, and only usable client-side, explaining the OP's issue.

Answer (score 3):

The Hash value is for the anchor, so it is only client-side, it is often used in client-side framework like angular for client-side routing.

The anchor is NOT available server-side.

In your case you don't need an anchor, but a parameter value with a # break the query string the value is "Transaction Log #459505".

EDIT Naive solution that doesn't work, just let it ther for history, See Real solution below

The solution is to encode client-side and decode serveur-side

Encoding in javascript

```
   encodeURI("Transaction Log #459505")
   //result value "Transaction%20Log%20#459505"
```

Decode in Java

```
 java.net.URLDecoder.decode("Transaction%20Log%20#459505");
  //result  "Transaction Log #459505"
```

EDIT: But: Javascript doesn't encode in the same way than Java
So the correct answer (I hope)  is to manually replace all your # with %23, then Java will decode it normally, or to use encodeURIComponent as suggested in comments. For your need the replace solution seem to be enough.

Encode in Javascript:

```
encodeURI("yourUrl/Transaction Log #459505").replace(/#/,"%23")
//result: yourUrl/Transaction%20Log%20%23459505
```

The decode in Java doesn't change

```
java.net.URLDecoder.decode("Transaction%20Log%20#459505")
// result (java.lang.String) Transaction Log #459505
```

Sorry for long post, I didn't see the difference bettween Java and the JavaScrip Url encoding

Comment: `encodeURI` will not work for  `/ ? : @ & = + $ #` you need to use `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: Thancks: so Stange the behavior is different in Java and Javascript, i will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

the hash is an anchor:

see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchor_(HTML)#Anchor) for more information