# Query parameter values starting with # is not getting considered in Postman

Tags: mule, postman, mule-studio, mule-component

I developed one application in Mulesoft for calling a SOAP webservice. While making GET call to a SOAP web service from Postman, query parameter value starting with # is not getting considered by my Mulesoft mapping.

e.g: http://localhost:8080/appName?queryParam1=#abc

In my mule application, the value for queryParam1 is coming as empty value. Could some one explain the technical reason for this. Is # is considered as escape character from Postman or Mulesoft Transform Message activity? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841137/what-is-the-behavior-of-hash-in-query-string

Comment: A very good explanation around the technicality around using # is found in the link provided by by Brad Cooper. Thanks a lot, Brad.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue in my API, in URI anywhere in between comes the '#' character the rest of your URI will go blank and the 404 HTTP error will occur.

I suggest you to get the value in query parameter without # character and later in the API code or flow prefix it. This will work.

Hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: Yes Kunal, you are correct. But we can encode the # with %23 as suggested by Sagar. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to encode characters such as **#**. Refer [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for complete list of such characters. In your example:

**Change:** http://localhost:8080/appName?queryParam1=#abc

**To:** http://localhost:8080/appName?queryParam1=%23abc