# Phalcon does not receive GET URI with escaped html characters

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I have a GET URI

```
/phalcon-dash/change/action/get/c123h%23516466
```

In ChangeController, I only have this

```
$params = array('get', 'c123h')
```

It looks like Phalcon omits everything after `#` (`%23` is the encoded of `#`)

Do I need to do anything to make Phalcon receives everything?

Comment: All the string after `#` does not return to server, so you couldn't get the string, See this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280212/getting-the-full-url-including-the-query-string-after-hash).

Comment: looks like I'll need to send a POST request with data instead of using GET